# PHP Sever Sent Events

Tags: php, server-sent-events

I have a php server sent events script as below:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
$message = rand(5, 15);
echo "data: {$message}\n\n";
ob_flush();
flush();
```

When I try to access the page script the browser downloads the file.
Is there a way to prevent that? For security reasons, I do not want users to download the file and read its content.

Thanks.

Comment: The browser does not download your PHP file but a file with your `data: ...` string

Comment: Yes, I did not check the file so I though code would be there. So is it normal or is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: If a script running on the user's browser need to read it, the user can read it too